# pgAdmin4: How do I edit the SELECT query generated by "View/Edit Data > All Rows"?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I recently migrated from MariaDB and there was a useful shortcut to construct a query in MySQL Workbench - you would right click the table and select "Select rows - Limit 1000". pgAdmin4 has an identical shortcut **however** I cannot edit the query in the Query Editor after the query has run. The query is grayed out/disabled.

Is there a way to "unlock" the input and make it editable, so I can adjust the query and re-run it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View/Edit Data` page is just a limited version of the Query Tool, according to pgAdmin's documentation<sup>[1](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/editgrid.html#the-view-edit-data-toolbar)</sup>:

> The Query Tool and View/Edit Data tools are actually different operating modes of the same tool. Some controls will be disabled in either mode. Please see The Query Tool Toolbar for a description of the available controls.

So use Query Tool (accessible from the same context menu) instead of using View/Edit Data. You can edit the query there.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame it's this way. Maybe they'll allow query editing in future versions.

Comment: @tom_nb_ny Yeah, I started using pgAdmin recently and in the first days, I had the same problem as you, hopefully, they'll do something about it soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Scripts > SELECT Script` which opens the Query Tool with a pre-filled script that does the same as `View/Edit Data > All Rows`

[image: pgadmin4 - table dialogue SELECT Script]

[image: pgadmin4 - pre-filled Query Tool with SELECT Script]